# "Introduced global variable(s) _firebug" in QUnit tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jquery-ui, qunit

I am using QUnit to perform various simple tests on my website. One of the tests is creating a dialog, showing it and then closing it. The test runs fine, but when run on Firefox with Firebug activated I get an error:

```
3. Introduced global variable(s): _firebug
```

I can live with it, but it is annoying: the same code on Chrome runs fine. I ruled out jQuery UI as the culprit since the same error appears without it. However, running without Firebug *or* without console.log traces does not show the problem.

I grepped all the javascript code I am using and found no mention of any "firebug" variables; and Google was silent on the matter. I want my green screen (all tests passed) back! Any ideas?

Comment: You specifically mentioned "with Firebug activated", can we assume that it doesn't happen with Firebug disabled? If that's the case, I'd be looking at Firebug and seeing what it is doing during your tests - it may be that Firebug is complaining about some part of the jQuery UI code (or your usage of it), and that in turn is creating that global variable.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Running without Firebug doesn't show the problem. But it is even worse: running with Firebug _and without any console.log traces_ the problem is not reproduced. Furthermore: running the original test again but without jQuery UI shows the same problem. So it seems to be a weird combination of Firebug and console.log -- I will update the question accordingly. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After googling a little bit more, I am not the first to find this problem: [badglobals.js](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/Finding-Improper-JavaScript-Globals), [blog](http://mankzblog.wordpress.com/tag/javascript/), [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/group/jsmentors/msg/92a0645ed9a5a4b7?hl=en). The solution to my particular problem (QUnit reports a leaky global variable) is to add the declaration of the global before starting the tests, for example before the first module is run:

```
var _firebug;
module('myModule');
```

I am seeing a spurious *xdc* variable too; same solution. My first QUnit test file now looks like this:

```
/* declare spurious Firebug globals */
var _firebug;
var _xdc_;

/* run tests */
module('myModule');
```

My bar is all green now, even with noglobals checked! I hope this helps anyone else who finds this annoying issue.